# Google maps marker gets duplicated

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I came across a problem. I have a simple app using google maps. I noticed if I work with two monitors and I have browser opened on one monitor and drag it to other monitor, marker gets duplicated after adding animation. Anyone else came across this, or have any idea how to fix it? Is the problem my code, or is it a google map bug?

It is not a big problem, but it is enough to annoy me.

I created a `jsfiddle` recreating my circumstances. Open `jsfiddle` on one monitor and drag it to other, then click bounce button. The problem also appears if you open developer tools and select another device.

https://jsfiddle.net/x4gM4/11/

HTML:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:300px;width:600px;background-color:#CCC"></div>
<button id="button">
 BOUNCE
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var marker;
var map;
function initialize() {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4375, 12.3358),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: myLatLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    });
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", bounceMarker);
};

function bounceMarker() {
        if(marker.getAnimation() == null){
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      setTimeout(function(){
        marker.setAnimation(null);
      }, 700);
    }
};

initialize();
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it, but delete `marker.setMap(map);` it's redundant.

Comment: @randomguy04 Thanks for comment, was extending someone elses jsfiddle. Try to open jsfiddel normally, then open developer tools, change device and then click bounce button. If I do that, I see two markers, one bouncing and one fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an odd one, but it seems it was to do with your bounceMarker() function. I have simplified it to:

```
function bounceMarker() {

  marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

};
```

And the problem disappears - https://jsfiddle.net/8jmw24ee/

Comment: Thank you for your help, but actually if change monitor before clicking bounce button, I still get two markers with your example.

Comment: you're right, sorry about that. I haven't been able to find any way around it. Seems like a slightly odd rendering bug.